# Keras : addition layer for embeddings / vectors?

Tags: python, nlp, keras, layer, embedding

I have 3 word embeddings :

- embedding#1 : [w11, w12, w13, w14]
- embedding#2 : [w21, w22, w23, w24]
- embedding#3 : [w31, w32, w33, w34]

Is there a way to get a fourth embedding by adding all three vectors, with the trainable weights from all of them, like:

- embedding#4  : [w11 + w21 + w31, w12 + w22 + w32, w13 + w23 + w33, w14 + w24 + w34]

?  Is there a way to do this in a keras layer?

**Problem**
I want to learn the word embeddings for Indonesian language.  I plan to do this by training a sequence prediction machine using LSTMs.

However, the grammar of Indonesian language is different from english.  Especially, in Indonesian, you can modify a word using prefixes and suffixes.  A noun word when given a prefix can become a verb, and when given a suffix can become an adjective.   You can put so many into one word, so that a single base word can have 5 or more variations.

For example  :

1. tani means farm (verb)
2. pe-tani means farmer
3. per-tani-an means farm (noun)
4. ber-tani means farm (verb, with slightly different meaning)

The transformation of semantic done by appending a prefix to a word is consistent between words.  For example  :

1. pe-tani is to tani is what pe-layan is to layan, what pe-layar is to layar, what pe-tembak is to tembak, and so on.
2. per-main-an is to main is what per-guru-an is to guru, what per-kira-an is to kira, what per-surat-an is to surat, and so on.

Therefore, i plan to represent the prefixes and suffixes as embeddings, which would be used to do an addition to the base word's embedding, producing a new embedding.  So the meaning of the composite word is derived from the embeddings of the base word and the affixes, not stored as a separate embeddings.   However i don't know how to do this in a Keras layer. If it had been asked before, i cannot find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "three word embeddings", I see three Embedding layers, such as:

```
input1 = Input((sentenceLength,))
input2 = Input((sentenceLength,))
input3 = Input((sentenceLength,))

emb1 = Embedding(...options...)(input1)
emb2 = Embedding(...options...)(input2)
emb3 = Embedding(...options...)(input3)
```

You can use a simple `Add()` layer to sum the three:

```
summed = Add()([emb1,emb2,emb3])
```

Then you continue your modeling...

```
#after creating the rest of the layers and getting the desired output:
model = Model([input1,input2,input3],output)
```

---

If you're not using embedding layers, but you're inputting three vectors:

```
input1 = Input((4,)) #or perhaps (sentenceLength,4)
input2 = Input((4,))
input3 = Input((4,))

added = Add()([input1,input2,input3])
```

And the rest is the same.

---

If this is not your question, please give more details about where the three "word embeddings" are coming from, how you intend to select them, etc.

Comment: I think this is what i'm looking for.  Thanks.