# Multiple embedding layers in keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, embedding, word-embedding

With pretrained embeddings, we can specify them as weights in keras' embedding layer. To use multiple embeddings, would specifying multiple embedding layer be suitable? i.e.

```
embedding_layer1 = Embedding(len(word_index) + 1,
                        EMBEDDING_DIM,
                        weights=[embedding_matrix_1],
                        input_length=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,
                        trainable=False)

 embedding_layer2 = Embedding(len(word_index) + 1,
                        EMBEDDING_DIM,
                        weights=[embedding_matrix_2],
                        input_length=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,
                        trainable=False)

 model.add(embedding_layer1)
 model.add(embedding_layer2)
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47326026/keras-addition-layer-for-embeddings-vectors) suggests to sum them up and represent them into a single layer, which is not what I am after.

Answer (score 1):

I have come across the same issue.Is it because keras.Embedding layer internally uses some kind of object (lets call it x_object ) ,that gets initialized in keras.backend global session K.
Hence the second embedding layer throws an exception saying the x_object name already exists in graph and cannot be added again.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use multiple embedding layers in a model the answer is in this thread
[Multiple Embedding layers for Keras Sequential model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50824417/multiple-embedding-layers-for-keras-sequential-model)